# Sort by associative column in an array csv

Tags: php, arrays, csv, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array by the 8th column. The column 8 stores data like position 1, position 2, position 3, etc.  col8 has to be associated only with the col7 because col7 holds the answers that should be sorted by the col8. For example, if col8 =position 1 and col7= yellow, col8 =position 2 and col7= black, it should print yellow black.
I tried to implement all the examples that I found here, but it is not working.

```
    function readCsv($fileName){

    $handle = fopen($fileName, "r");

    $data=array();

    while ($col = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) { 

        $data[] = [

            'Section' => $col[0],   
            'Q #' => $col [1],
            'Q Type' => $col[2],
            'Q Title' => $col[3],
            'Q Text' => $col[4],
            'Bonus' => $col [5],
            'Difficulty' => $col[6],
            'Answer' => $col[7],
            'Answer Match' => $col[8],
            'Responses'=> $col[9], 

        ]; 

    }

   usort($data, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a["Answer Match"], $b["Answer Match"]); });


    fclose($handle);
    return $data;
}
```

[image]

Should return yellow black purple.

I try to use this code:

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a["Answer Match"], $b["Answer Match"]); });
```

However, it is sorting Column 1, and not Colum 7.

[image]

My output is giving incorrect, because it prints the header (# Partipant) and put the participants in alphabetical order:

1> Participant 2    Orange  White Black
2> # Participant    Black Yellow  Purple

The correct output will be:

1> Participant 1    Yellow Black Purple

2> Participant 2    Orange  Black White

Comment: what should print yellow black? a little bit unclearly...

Comment: provide example of csv, and example of result (if you have one or you can do one)

Comment: @MrSmile It should print first yellow because column 8 has position 1. I would like to sort by the position and not by the alphabetical order of the column 7.

Comment: @MrSmile I include the table in the question  above.

Comment: How many rows do you have? You probably want to go through all rows first in order to determine every row position, right?

Comment: @HtmHell It has 9 colums and 95 lines.

Comment: @HtmHell I updated my code just now.

Comment: @find83 You should add to your question a few lines from your CSV file, as a plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use usort after **while**, when you already have all dataset. And your compare function wasn't good, look here:

```
function readCsv($fileName){
$handle = fopen($fileName, "r");
$data=array();
while ($col = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) {
    $data[] = [
        'Section' => $col[0],
        'Q #' => $col[1],
        'Q Type' => $col[2],
        'Q Title' => $col[3],
        'Q Text' => $col[4],
        'Bonus' => $col [5],
        'Difficulty' => $col[6],
        'Answer' => $col[7],
        'Answer Match' => $col[8],
        'Responses'=> $col[9],

    ];
}
usort($data, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a["Answer Match"], $b["Answer Match"]); });
fclose($handle);
return $data;
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: My array has 9 columns and 95 lines. For some reason, your solution sort the first column and not the columns 7 and 8. :(

Comment: @find83, it's strange, cause I've tested script. Take a look at my edited post, maybe you've missed something.

Comment: I tried your code but it sorting only the column 1. I include more information in the question above.

Comment: @find83 please update your full function code. Are you sure that you run usort **after** while?

Comment: I updated my code just now. It still sorting Column 1 :(

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you only want to sort columns 7 and 8; and you want to leave columns 1...6,9 'unsorted'/left as they are. This is a little strange in the context of arrays, so it needs a little workaround:

```
//Your code for context
function readCsv($fileName){
$handle = fopen($fileName, "r");
$data=array();
while ($col = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) { 
    $data[] = //removed
}

//take columns 7 and 8 out, and sort them separately.
$sortedAnswer = array_column($data,'Answer','Answer Match');
ksort($sortedAnswer);
reset($sortedAnswer);

//pluck the columns back in.
$data = array_map(function($v) use (&$sortedAnswer) {
  $v['Answer'] = current($sortedAnswer);
  $v['Answer Match'] = key($sortedAnswer);
  next($sortedAnswer);
  return $v;
}, $data);
unset($sortedAnswer);

//your code for context
fclose($handle);
return $data;
}
```

It's possible, that I completely misunderstood your question. In that case I apologize.

ETA:
The array_map part is overly complicated without any reason; I'll change it to foreach once I know the answer is in the right direction.

Comment: Unfortunately, with your code, it is printing only the column 1.  It's not print column 7 and column 8 :(

Comment: Are you printing `$data`? `$sortedAnswer` is only a temporary variable that is useless afterword.

Comment: I'm printing $data. How can I use `$sortedAnswer` ins this case?

Comment: You should not use $sortedAnswer. That was just a guess by me, because I didn't understand how $data can have only one column; and I still don't.

Comment: I added some of your code to make sure we are talking about the same arrays.

Comment: $data have 9 columns. I want to sort by column 8, column 7. Others columns should not change.